# Setting the Return String from a Shell Script to a variable in another Shell Script

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a shell script that checks the output of a different script, however I am not sure how to extract the string from the called script.

My code is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
outputCheck=''
errorNames=()

echo 'Performing Test Checks on Cluster 2'
c2=('NAME_1' 'NAME_2')

for(( i=0; i<${#c2[@]}; i++ ));
do
    echo 'Checking' ${c2[i]}
    ./scripts/SCRIPT_FILE.sh -v ${c2[i]} check | $outputCheck  #this is the line that doesn't do what I expect
    # expect '$outputCheck' to equal 'No errors found.' if okay
    if [ "$outputCheck" !=  "No errors found." ];
        then
            echo $outputCheck
            errorNames+=(${c2[i]})
        else
            # for testing code only
            echo $outputCheck
    fi
done

echo 'Check complete'
if [ "${#errorNames[@]}" != 0 ];
    then
        echo "The following tests had errors:"
        for(( i=1; i<=${#errorNames[@]}; i++ ));
        do
            echo $i: ${errorNames[i-1]}
        done
fi
```

If I run 'SCRIPT_FILE' in the terminal, I get the expected 'No errors found.' for both 'NAME_1' and 'NAME_2', however in my script file, '$outputCheck' is an empty string every time (what it is initialised to) and so they are added to the 'errorNames' array despite not containing errors, so I have reason to suspect my method here is not good.

How can I obtain and use the output from 'SCRIPT_FILE' to make this work?

Comment: Why not just store all output status' to the array and loop later to determine, if string is empty test has passed and failure if not?

Comment: @Inian The problem is that nothing seems to be getting piped into '$outputCheck' (the variable string) so, even if I did put all status' into an array, it would be empty and hence would be a false positive test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping is used to pass the standard output from one process to the standard error of another; you cannot pipe output directly to a variable to perform an assignment.

Instead, use command substitution:

```
for f in "${c2[@]}"; do
    outputCheck=$(./scripts/SCRIPT_FILE.sh -v "${f}" check)
    if [[ $outputCheck != "No errors found." ]]; then
        errorNames+=("$f")
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$outputCheck"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it worked. One of those things that seems so obvious once you see it! Just a couple of things, if you could add the closing square brackets to the if statement in your solution that would be great, and any idea why my question was downvoted? (Just so I can try and improve)